# Editing date and updating it in FireBase with vue.js , vuex?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I'm a beginner in writing vue js. I want to edit an exiting date in the app am working on based on a tutorial video am watching and the new date should be updated both in the app and Firebase when the SAVE button is clicked.
Am getting an error this which i think is not allowing the `v-dialog` to show but when i change the `v-model` in the `v-date-picker` to date which is included in my data as

```
 props: ['meetup'],
        data () {
          return {
            editDialog: false,
            editableDate: null,
            date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10)
          }
        }
```

the `v-dialog` works with no error but i get this error when the `v-model` is changed from `date` to `editableDate`:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:587 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Array, String, got Date.
>
> vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:587 [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: dateString.split is not a function"
>
> vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1737 TypeError: dateString.split is not a function
>
> vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:587 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'isDark' of undefined"
>
> TypeError: Cannot set property 'isDark' of undefined

```
  <template>
    <v-dialog width="350px" persistent v-model="editDialog" ref="dialog" lazy full-width>
        <v-btn accent slot="activator">
            Edit Date
        </v-btn>
        <v-card>
            <v-container>
                <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                        <v-card-title>Edit Meetup Date</v-card-title>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-divider></v-divider>
                <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                        <v-date-picker v-model="editableDate" style="width: 100%" actions>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <template slot-scope="{save, cancel}">
                            <v-btn
                                class="blue--text darken-1"
                                flat
                                @click.native="editDialog = false">
                                Close
                                </v-btn>
                                <v-btn
                                class="blue--text darken-1"
                                flat
                                @click.native="onSaveChanges">
                                Save
                            </v-btn>
                        </template>
                        </v-date-picker>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>
```

scripts

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['meetup'],
    data () {
      return {
        editDialog: false,
        editableDate: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSaveChanges () {
        const newDate = new Date(this.meetup.date)
        const newDay = new Date(this.editableDate).getUTCDate()
        const newMonth = new Date(this.editableDate).getUTCMonth()
        const newYear = new Date(this.editableDate).getUTCFullYear()
        newDate.setUTCDate(newDay)
        newDate.setUTCMonth(newMonth)
        newDate.setUTCFullYear(newYear)
        this.$store.dispatch('updateMeetupData', {
          id: this.meetup.id,
          date: newDate
        })
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.editableDate = new Date(this.meetup.date)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Have tried all i could but to no avail please i need help

This is my store

```
updateMeetupData ({commit}, payload) {
  commit('setLoading', true)
  const updateObj = {}
  if (payload.title) {
    updateObj.title = payload.title
  }
  if (payload.description) {
    updateObj.description = payload.description
  }
  if (payload.date) {
    updateObj.date = payload.date
  }
  firebase.database().ref('meetups').child(payload.id).update(updateObj)
    .then(() => {
      commit('setLoading', false)
      commit('updateMeetup', payload)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      commit('setLoading', false)
    })
},
```

Comment: there is nowhere near enough information provided here. There is no information on what your store looks like. This is a firebase question and there is no firebase code provided.

Comment: @Aaron Saunders have edited my question, i hope it's better now